# I am having differences between manually downloading with download.file in R

Tags: r, download

I have created the following function:

```
download_ <- function(zip_link, destination){
  zip_url <- zip_link
  zip_file <- file.path(destination, basename(zip_link))
  
  download.file(zip_url, destfile = zip_file, cacheOK = FALSE)
}

download_(zip_link = "https://datosabiertos.mineduc.cl/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/Asistencia-declarada-Abril-2022.rar", 
          destination = "C:/Users/####/Desktop")
```

And it downloads the April 2022 file like this:

[image: Code Download]

But if I download it manually:

[image]

What's going on here? What is my code doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't your current `download.file()` result just corrupt? Try with `download.file(zip_url, destfile = zip_file, cacheOK = FALSE, mode = "wb")` . Also, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+download.file+corrupt

Comment: epa! it worked! thanks, but would you mind explaining to me what does it mean when the file is corrupt?

Comment: It means that your local copy is different from the original  / remote for whatever reason (failing hardware, interrupted download,  wrong mode when using `download.file()`in windows  and countless other reasons ) and content can't be used or should not be trusted.  7zip should start complaining when you attempt to extract that broken rar but your Q title left an impression that the file was kind of fine, just different.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the explanations. Would you mind posting this as an answer? So I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When downloading binary files in Windows with `download.file()`, a proper mode should be set with `mode = "wb"`, so the call becomes:

```r
download.file(zip_url, destfile = zip_file, cacheOK = FALSE, mode ="wb")
```

It can get bit confusing at times as for certain URL patterns it is set automagically and downloaded files can end up OK, i.e. URLs ending with *".zip"*. It also wouldn't hurt to always use binary mode. Or use something with more practical defaults, like `curl::curl_download()`.

From `?download.file()`:

> The choice of binary transfer (mode = "wb" or "ab") is important on Windows, since unlike Unix-alikes it does distinguish between text and binary files and for text transfers changes \n line endings to \r\n (aka ‘CRLF’).
>
> On Windows, if mode is not supplied (missing()) and url ends in one of .gz, .bz2, .xz, .tgz, .zip, .jar, .rda, .rds or .RData, mode = "wb" is set so that a binary transfer is done to help unwary users.
>
> Code written to download binary files must use mode = "wb" (or "ab"), but the problems incurred by a text transfer will only be seen on Windows.